# Is trace map uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

> We have trace map as $tr : M_n(F) \to F.$

Then using trace map is linear map I get $||tr(A)-tr(B)||=||tr(A-B)|| \le ||tr||||A-B||.$

Since I know that trace is a continuous map, I have $||tr||$ as Lipschitz constant. (Because $||tr||=\sup_{||A||=1}||tr(A)||$ and as the set $||A||=1$ is compact, the image $tr(A)$ is also compact hence obtaining maximum and minimum.)

By Lipschitz condition, I get trace map is uniformly continuous.

Am I right?

Comment: More simply, trace is a linear mapping on a finite dimensional normed vector space, so it is continuous. Any continuous linear map is Lipschitz by default, $\therefore$ uniformly continuous.

Comment: @OpenBall did you forget to put the word 'linear' after the word 'trace'?

Comment: Yes; I added it.

Comment: @OpenBall So general result is "Any continuous linear map on a finite dimensional normed vector space is uniformly continuous." Thanks. +1.